# Calculate distance in MongoDB map-reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, distance

I have a MongoDB collection with a geo index:

```
> db.coll.getIndexes()
[
    // ...
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "location" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "ns" : "test.coll",
        "dropDups" : false,
        "name" : "location_2dsphere",
        "background" : false
    }
]

db.coll.findOne({location: {'$exists': true}}, {'location': 1})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52cd72ae2ac170aa3eaace6e"),
    "location" : [
        55.4545177559,
        11.5767419669
    ]
}
```

On which I'm running map reduce, which looks something like this:

```
var map = function() {
     var value = 0;

     // ... various calculations on the value here

     var distance = 0; // < This is the problematic part
     if (distance < 1000) {
         val += distance;  // for example
     }

     emit(this._id, value)
}
var reduce = function(id, val) {
    return {id: val}
}

db.coll.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {inline: 1}})
```

Is there a way to calculate the distance between `location` and point X, in the map function?

I'm looking for something like [$geoNear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/), but somehow combined with the map-reduce.

For example:

```
db.runCommand({geoNear: "coll", near: [-74, 40.74], spherical: true})
```

Returns the distance for each document. But I can't find a way to combine it with the map-reduce command.

Comment: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: Doing it in pure js isn't optimal, since mongo already supports distance calculation...

Comment: As to "what I tried", I'm running `geonear` queries and map-reduce on the collection. Looking for a way to combine the 2.

Comment: @YuriPrezument you might also qualify **what** you are trying to do in `mapReduce` rather than just ask "can I use it" and perhaps someone might have a suggestion to "what you are **trying** to do". As yet, we can't see that. Note you are on the close vote list, so it would be better for you to qualify what it is you want.

Comment: @NeilLunn Just need to do some calculation based on distance, currently I'm calculating other stuff there which is irrelevant to the question itself.
Regarding the close vote, IMHO it's unjustified and comes from misunderstanding the question, but we'll see...

Comment: Added more details to the example in case it helps to understand the question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Great Circle Formula is the way to go http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

I ran in to a similar problem with mongo and js. And came up with this function. Hope it helps.

```
function find(point, latlng, radius){
       var dist = parseInt(radius) * 0.868976 / 60; // convert miles to rad

    if((point[0] <= latlng[0] + dist && point[1] >= latlng[1]- dist) 
    && (point[0] <= latlng[0]+ dist && point[1] >= latlng[1]- dist)){

        dx = latlng[0] - point[0];
        dy = latlng[1] - point[1];
        dx *= dx;
        dy *= dy;
        ds = dx + dy;
        rs = dist * dist;
        is =  ds <= rs;

        return is;
    }
}
```

Im calling this like this:

```
find([-79,5], [40,20], 5);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I already solved it in another way (doing the distance calculation in Python instead), but this seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late addition but for other folks coming here it might be good to know about a suite of Javascript libraries that are available to do geo related functions.

https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib